# How can I avoid redundant imports in MEF?

Tags: c#, .net, mef, redundancy

Here's the issue... if I use, say a directory catalog in MEF and have some.dll and copy of some.dll, i will get double the exports, even though they are defining the same type, is there a way to resolve this?

EDIT: the problem isn't with this particular issue, this is just an abstract example of a real issue, for instance, if i have an "extensions" folder, and a way to manually import... it's just something that would be nice to handle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a `FilteredCatalog` (not part of the core MEF distribution.) See the example here: http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Filtering%20Catalogs

Rather than selecting from the inner catalogs via `Where` you may use `Distinct`. To compare `ComposablePartDefinition`s for equality the simplest option is to use `ToString` but casting to `ReflectionComposablePartDefinition` is also an option.

HTH,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to resolve this?

Two options come to mind:

- remove the redundant copy of the
  assembly
- don't use a directory catalog. You
  can add assembly catalogs for each
  individual assembly, and just leave
  out the unwanted assemblies.